# axios delete method gives 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, csrf, interceptor

I am calling delete method from my node-js application.

> Its working fine from Postman but giving me 403 while calling this API
>   from code.

Below is my sample code snippet:

```
const instance = axios.create();
instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.baseURL = 'https://test-dev.com/api/portfolio'
    config.headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + <TOKEN>}
    return config;
});
instance.delete('/admin?users=<VALUE>').then(function(response) {
    console.log("Deleted: "+<VALUE>);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Deletion failed with error:" + error);
});
```

**EDIT:**

Response (Coming from spring security APP):

> Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found

I thought this is already handled by axios.

How can i pass this value in headers while calling delete method?

Any help?

Comment: can you share server code also?

Comment: Actually it is being handled by other team, so not able to check that for the moment.
My given code seems right?
I just want to confirm anything strange is not in it :)

Comment: Try it with `config.crossDomain: true` in your interceptor. Then axios will made the preflight options request first. Perhaps it helps...

Comment: @ThomasKleßen i tried what you said. Same error!

Comment: @JayeshDhandha did any comments or answers help you with your issue? do you need more assistance? let us know

Comment: @c-chavez I solved by doing some changes at API which I am calling using axios. Now it's working!

Comment: @JayeshDhandha If none of the answers helped you, add your own so that others benefit from your solution :)

Comment: I have marked your solution as correct because this also works at some stage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

**1 - Use the withCredentials property:**

```
withCredentials: true
```

so:

```
axios.delete({
    url: 'https://test-dev.com/api/portfolio/admin?users=' + <VALUE>,
    headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + <TOKEN>},
    withCredentials: true
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log("Deleted: "+<VALUE>);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Deletion failed with error:" + error);
});
```

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that
>   indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be
>   made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS
>   client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on
>   same-site requests.

**2 - Set CSRF headers**

Either:

```
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')}
```

or

```
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
         'X-CSRFToken': 'your token here'}
```

or just:

```
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

**3 - Disable at own risk and if possible**

Have a look at [this article](https://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/)

Answer (score 0):

So after a number of tries, I found it working.

**Please follow the order sequence** it's very important else it won't work

```
axios.delete(
        URL,
        {headers: {
          Authorization: authorizationToken
        },
        data:{
          source:source
        }}
      );
```