# axios.delete() is giving 403 error ... however this works in POSTMAN, and axios.post method is working fine

Tags: java, reactjs, axios

I have a REACT front-end interacting with an STS (java) backend.

DELETE function:

```
deleteCustomer = (someone) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/customer/" + `${someone}`
    axios.delete(url)

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Deletion failed with error: " + error);
    });
  }
```

HTML where it's triggered:

```
      {this.state.customers.map(p => (

        <span onClick={() => this.deleteCustomer(p.customerid)} title="Delete Customer"><img alt="delete" className="hiddenIcon actionDelete" src={deleteHover} /></span>

        ))}
```

In Java back-end the delete method looks like this:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{customerid}")
  public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long customerid) {
    customerRepository.deleteById(customerid);
  }
```

So when I run a DELETE type request in POSTMAN application, the record is deleted without any issue.  However, trying to run the function from React front-end is giving ERROR 403 (network error) when trying to run. 
I am assuming that there is some header or parameter I am missing?  If AUTHORIZATION is required, how do I find my authorization key?

I tried to follow this: 
[axios delete method gives 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836854/axios-delete-method-gives-403) 
But didn't get any resolution.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Did you try a get request from the browser to the resource? If it's Cors issue, you would know. Apart from that 403 indicates server rejection. Make sure you pass required headers that you need? This information isn't sufficient as we have no idea on what basis server rejects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related with CORS, try adding the `@CrossOrigin` annotation to your endpoint like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@DeleteMapping("/{customerid}")
public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long customerid) {
    customerRepository.deleteById(customerid);
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do it!  You have made my entire day.  Thank you very much!